# Where can I adjust the brightness in Starfield?

Tags: starfield

I have just started my first shift on Starfield.
In the first mine the light seems to be much too bright.

Where can I adjust the brightness?

(Or do I have to adjust my monitor itself or the brigthness in my Windows to get a darker light in the mine?)

Comment: I believe I read that there is no such setting, but I can't confirm myself until Tuesday.

Comment: Do you have an NVIDIA graphics card, by chance? There's a [post](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=3028928827) on the Steam forums with some NVIDIA-specific workarounds.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas Yes, NVIDIA. Please follow the note: "You MUST be logged into NVidia GeForce Experience for this panel (Alt+F3) to work." Then you can adjust the Filter Sharpen: 50% / Clarity: 100% / HDR Toning: -100% / Bloom: 0%.

Comment: Bethesda has announced that an upcoming patch will add Brightness and Contrast controls in game.

Comment: @Mufasa - Yep. The update patch v1.8.86 added it (2023-11-20). I wrote this fact in a new answer including a link with all other patch notes at Bethesda.

Answer (score 5):

While Starfield itself doesn't currently provide this option, there are some workarounds available for certain graphics cards. On 13 September 2023, Bethesda [announced](https://store.steampowered.com/news/app/1716740/view/3687940304703443230?l=english) a series of small upcoming patches to include commonly requested functionality which includes "Brightness and Contrast controls."

---

For **NVidia cards**, there's a guide on [Steam](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=3028928827) to add a 'game filter' to adjust for the brightness. This requires you to be logged into GEForce Experience and use the overlay.

- Open the GEForce Experience overlay.
- Select 'Game Filter'.

[image: GEForce Experience overlay, Game Filter option]

- Select a preset (1, 2, 3). This allows you to save groups of filters.
- Add a new 'Details' filter by selecting that type from the drop-down.

[image: Selecting a details filter]

- Adjust settings as desired. The steam guide suggests the following, but adjust based on your preferences/monitor:

  - Sharpen: 50%
  - Clarity: 100%
  - HDR Toning: -100%
  - Bloom: 0%
- Save the filter with 'Done'.

See the [linked guide](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=3028928827) for before/after screenshots. <sub>(While I can apply the filter, I don't have the problem to start out with so it ends up making my game unpleasantly dark. So while the screenshots in this post are my own, you should look at the screenshots in the linked Steam guide for examples of the results.)</sub>

---

For **AMD cards**, the solution may be to adjust contrast and brightness in the [AMD settings](https://www.reddit.com/r/Starfield/comments/166skud/where_the_heck_is_the_brightness_or_gamma_slider/jym333a). There don't seem to be any more detailed or fine-grained workarounds available for these graphics cards yet.

Comment: The patch you mentioned appears to be [available now](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/404219/where-can-i-adjust-the-brightness-in-starfield#comment568702_404219) if you wish to update your answer

Comment: @TimmyJim Thanks, I'll update my answer when I get off work and can get to my computer to take some screenshots of the new screens.

Answer (score 3):

Since the newest available update patch v1.8.86 from 2023-11-20 there is an option in the settings to adjust Brightness and Contrast in the Display Settings menu.

Bethesda also added the ability to adjust HDR Brightness provided that the system supports it. (Xbox & Windows 11 only).

https://bethesda.net/en/game/starfield/article/3V830KanHH0I2zTIKraEih/starfield-update-1-8-86-notes-november-20-2023

Answer (score 1):

There is no brightness / gamma / contrast option at this moment, unfortunately.